# field list error - unknown column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS buildMySomething;
CREATE PROCEDURE buildMySomething() 
BEGIN
      UPDATE current_amount SET current_m_amount = 2 WHERE m_id = 1; 
END //
```

This gives me the following error : `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknowing column 'current_m_amount' in 'field list'`

After looking around on the internet, it is apparent to me that people get this error if the column does not exist, an unexpected character, or simply a syntax error (they have typed the column name wrong)... however... i have checked these possibilities a countless number of times. what am i missing here?

```
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| m_id               | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| current_m_amount   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Can you update your question with `current_amount` table description.

Comment: Post the schema, please. I'll put money on there being no column of that name

Comment: What is the datatype of `current_m_amount` column ?

Comment: @BlueMonster, remove  `()` from your stored procedure and try.

Comment: @BlueMonster Ok - you've got me. I'm stumped.

Comment: @AlpeshGediya i tried that just now, and it still gives the same error. If i remove the line altogether it's fine. In fact i can add in all sorts of other lines of code (SELECT on that column etc) and it all works fine..

Comment: @BlueMonster, your error message compaints about `'field list'` but you have provided description of `Field`, how they are related ?  are you sure you are using correct database name while creating storedprocedure? do you have space in your table name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be something to do with the delimiter in use. Try this, which executes on my test server:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS buildMySomething;
delimiter //

CREATE PROCEDURE buildMySomething() 
BEGIN
      UPDATE current_amount SET current_m_amount = 2 WHERE m_id = 1; 
END //
delimiter ;
```